# Is it possible to replace an upgrade you've added to an item?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I currently don't have enough level 80 upgrades to apply to all of my items. I do, however, have a variety of lower level upgrades that I can apply.

If I apply one of these upgrades to an item, is it possible to then replace it at a later date with a higher level upgrade or do I need to re-create the item in order to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may "override" upgrades at any time, simply by attaching the upgrade over the upgrade item. (You'll get a prompt warning you that this will destroy the current upgrade).

It is possible to recover the upgrade and destroy the item (guaranteed with Black Lion Salvage Kit), but it is not possible, once upgrade, to reobtain **both** base items.

Comment: Is this prompt similar to changing gems in World of Warcraft?

Comment: @pixel Eurgh, it's been years since I've played WoW. So not sure, but I'd wager yes.

Comment: Ah yeah, I've tested it now, at least it gives you a warning, which is why I didn't want to test that in the first place ;)